# How to install pysqlite2 on Debian Squeeze?

Tags: python, linux, unix, debian, pysqlite

I have a bit of a problem. I am on Debian Squeeze, and I want to install sqlite2. The problem is, when I try with:

```
# pip install pysqlite2
```

I get:

```
Downloading/unpacking pysqlite2
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pysqlite2
No distributions at all found for pysqlite2
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

The same error I get when I try with:

```
# pip install python-pysqlite2
```

I also tried with easy_install:

```
# easy_install pysqlite2
Searching for pysqlite2
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pysqlite2/
Couldn't find index page for 'pysqlite2' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pysqlite2
Best match: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1712, in main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1700, in with_ei_usage
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1716, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 434, in easy_install
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/package_index.py", line 475, in fetch_distribution
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

I also tried with downloading the pyslite2 package from [here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/python-pysqlite2-dbg), and when I try with:

```
# dpkg -i python-pysqlite2-dbg_2.6.0-1_amd64.deb
```

I get the following error:

```
Selecting previously deselected package python-pysqlite2-dbg.
(Reading database ... 144103 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python-pysqlite2-dbg (from python-pysqlite2-dbg_2.6.0-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pysqlite2-dbg:
 python-pysqlite2-dbg depends on python-pysqlite2 (= 2.6.0-1); however:
  Package python-pysqlite2 is not configured yet.
 python-pysqlite2-dbg depends on python-dbg; however:
  Package python-dbg is not installed.
dpkg: error processing python-pysqlite2-dbg (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pysqlite2-dbg
```

I would really appriciate help for this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run apt-get install to install all missing dependencies:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Sorry I am late with the answer Oleksandr, I simply forgot to answer after I tried this because I had to do so many other things. This solved my problem, thanks a lot! Cheers!